# How to preserver order of test and suite-files in TestNG during running?

Tags: xml, testing, suite, order-of-execution

I have a suite like this:

```
<suite name="mySuite">
    <test name="myTest">
        <classes>
            <class name="Test"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <suite-files>
        <suite-file path="x.xml"/>
    </suite-files>
</suite>
```

where **x.xml** contains:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="mySuite2">
    <test name="myTest2">
        <classes>
            <class name="mypack.Test2"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

When I run the first suite, the order of execution is the following:

- Test2
- Test

How can I preserve the "declaration" order?

I'd like to have:

- Test
- Test2

Even if I use `<suite name="mySuite" preserve-order="true">`, I'm still getting the following order:

- Test2
- Test

It seems that the `preserve-order` attribute doesn't work for elements having different tag names (`test` vs `suite-files`). Is there any solution/workaround to achieve this?